# Need assistance with SVG elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm relatively new to SVG elements so I'm not entirely sure how this works properly, I'm having an issue removing an animated line, everytime I attempt to it breaks it.

Here's an example: http://www.mistersmedirectory.com/?page_id=4339

Here's the code (hit the character limit, had to use pastebin: http://pastebin.com/siXM69Vd)

Essentially, I just want to remove the animated line on the example that goes to nothing, but everytime I do it breaks, could someone point out to me the way to go about doing this

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected it in Firefox and deleted the node.

http://pastebin.com/1j2CA5Sn

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If removing that line breaks things then you just make bgfill color with transparent property

http://prntscr.com/7cljk7

Look this screenshot above i tried it in console and yeah i could'nt get access to your code so dint try there